# $\text{deg}(f)$ is not divisible by $[L:F]$

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

I am trying to recall an exam question so I am sorry if this question doesn't make full sense. I think some people would know what the actual wording should be after reading it.

---

$F \subseteq L$ is a field extension. Let $f$ be irreducible in $F[x]$. Show that if deg$(f)$ is not divisible by $[L:F]$, then $f$ contains no roots in $L$.

---

It did mention something about a simple extension like $F(a)$ (which is guess $a$ is in $L$) but I don't know how that went in the question.

Sorry if this thread seems quite stupid but I just really want to know how to do it.

I did: Let $h$ be the minimal polynomial of $u \in L$ over $F$. Let the degree of this polynomial be $n$ so $[L:K]=n$. Let $f$ be a polynomial of degree $m$. We cant have $m=n$, then degree of $f$ would be divisible by $n$ which cant happen by the question. So either $m>n$ of $m<n$. If $m<n$, then $f$ divided by $g$ would give $f=0$, which means no roots in $L$ from $f$. If $m>n$, then we can write $f=qg+r$ but didn't know what to do after.

Does my answer make any sense, would I get any credit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You recall wrongly the statement.

> Let $L$ be a finite extension field of $F$. If $f(x)\in F[x]$ is irreducible and $\deg(f)$ is not a divisor of $[L:F]$ then $f$ has no root in $L$.

If $\alpha\in L$ is a root of $f$, then $F(\alpha)\subseteq L$ and
$$
F(\alpha)\cong F[x]/(f(x))
$$
because $f$ is irreducible over $f$. Then $[F(\alpha):F]=\deg(f)$.

Apply the dimension formula: $[L:F]=[L:F(\alpha)]\,[F(\alpha):F]$.

Comment: Damn so my answer is fully wrong?

Comment: @cooldudeman I'm afraid so